# R join two dataframes but keep only one of duplicate columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to join two data frames which have some overlapping columns.  I am currently doing this like so:

```
library(dplyr)
final <-  full_join(df1, df2, by = "Id")
```

This works, except for the columns that both `df1` and `df2` have in common, it prefixes the shared columns with `.x` and `.y`.  What is the right way to join but keep only one instance of the shared column so no prefix is generated?

Comment: I think you need to consider what's in those columns. Are they identical? If not, you may need to keep both. Do you want to join on them in addition to `Id`? Do you even need them at all, in which case `select` them away. It all depends on their content and subsequent steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use {powerjoin}:

**data**

```r
df1 <- iris[c(1,51),4:5]
df2 <- iris[c(6,56),2:5]

df1
#>    Petal.Width    Species
#> 1          0.2     setosa
#> 51         1.4 versicolor

df2
#>    Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 6          3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
#> 56         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
```

**solution**

keep version from left table

```
library(powerjoin)
power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "Species", conflict = coalesce_xy)
#>      Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1     setosa         3.9          1.7         0.2
#> 2 versicolor         2.8          4.5         1.4
```

keep version from right table

```
power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "Species", conflict = coalesce_yx)
#>      Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1     setosa         3.9          1.7         0.4
#> 2 versicolor         2.8          4.5         1.3
```

combine them

```
power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "Species", conflict = `+`)
#>      Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1     setosa         3.9          1.7         0.6
#> 2 versicolor         2.8          4.5         2.7

power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "Species", conflict = pmin)
#>      Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1     setosa         3.9          1.7         0.2
#> 2 versicolor         2.8          4.5         1.3
```

If you don't want to resolve the conflict but want to fail if it happens, to avoid creating extra columns or desperately looking for columns renamed automatically, use the check argument (you can also "warn" or "inform")

```
power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "Species", check = check_specs(column_conflict = "abort"))
#> Error in `check_column_conflict()`:
#> ! The following columns are conflicted and their conflicts are not handled:  'Petal.Width'
```

Comment: (I needed to wait 1 minute).  Thanks!